# Custom Load / Hatch rate Locust

Tags: python, locust

I'm trying to implement a load test, which needs some setup done. So my initial idea was just blocking all workers after the first one until the first one completed its setup, this works fine for me.

But the Problem is, that while the first worker is doing it's setup workers are still spawning and after the lock ist lifted an Initial load spike from the workers accumulated can be observed. Since this is not desirable I want to postpone the spawning till the first worker finished.

If I would use a custom load shape I would have to hardcode the spawning rate, since the rate is never actually saved in the environment (unlike the total workers).

So my questions are:

- Is there any way to get the value without going too deep into rewriting the standard environment class?
- Is there a clever way to postpone spawning I haven't thought of?

This problem really bugs me out, I would appreciate an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `test_start` event? It runs before any ramp up is started.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#test-start-and-test-stop

It doesnt have access to a User (so use `requests` directly for any HTTP you want to call, or spawn your own locust.clients.HttpSession if you want to log the requests into locusts regular statistics)

(I'm assuming you mean "Users" when you say "workers". workers are actually locust processes in a distributed run, previously called slaves)